# to delete the value of the element in XML using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, shell, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to delete the value of the element in the xml using xmlstarlet:
I tried xmlstarlet ed -d command to delete the value but it did not work.
I also tried using xmlstarlet ed -u to replace the value 123 with ""(null). This did not work either.

Can someone please help me how to get this:
Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<List Name="myList">
  <Dir Path="abc">123</Dir>
  <Dir Path="cde">456</Dir>
  <File Path="xyz">789</File>
  <File Path="xxx">567</File>
</List>
```

Output:

```
<List Name="myList">
  <Dir Path="abc"></Dir>
  <Dir Path="cde"></Dir>
  <File Path="xyz"></File>
  <File Path="xxx"></File>
</List>
```

I want to delete the values "123", "456" ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the **exact** `xmlstarlet ed` commands you used; otherwise, we can't diagnose why they didn't work. Lots of different ways to use both `xmlstarlet ed -u` or `xmlstarlet ed -d`.

Comment: BTW, I'm still curious about the details of what you were trying earlier, just to better understand where it's easy for people to make mistakes here.

Comment: My xpath expr was wrong which I used to delete: xmlstarlet ed -d "//List/*" input.xml. This deleted all the tags instead of the values.

Comment: The second one xmlstar ed -u "//List/*" -v " " input.xml - this worked. My xpath expr had an extra tag earlier "//List/Dir/*" instead of "//List/*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all text nodes, leaving elements and their attributes:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//text()' <input.xml
```

...or, to replace the content of those text nodes with empty strings:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//text()' -v '' <input.xml
```

Comment: second one worked for me. xmlstarlet ed -u '//text()' -v '' input.xml

Comment: Interesting. They both work for me (with XMLStarlet 1.5.0 linked against libxml2 2.9.1), though the first one resulted in the semantically equivalent `<Dir Path="abc"/>` rather than `<Dir Path="abc"></Dir>`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to clarify that: I needed the second format as the output <Dir Path="abc"></Dir>  for my function though both are semantically equivalent.